# Component returned by custom hooks fire a ts error when called in JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i create that custom hook

```
// useDropdown.ts
function useDropdown(defaultState: number, options: number[]) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);
  function Dropdown({ name }: { name: string }) {
    return (
      <>
        <select
          name={name}
          value={state}
          onChange={(e) => setState(Number(e.target.value))}
          onBlur={(e) => setState(Number(e.target.value))}
          disabled={options.length === 0}
        >
          {options.map((item) => (
            <option key={item} value={item}>
              {item}h
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </>
    );
  }

  return [state, Dropdown, setState];
}

export default useDropdown;
```

```
// HourPicker.ts
const HourPicker = ({ day, label }: HourPickerProps) => {
  const [checked, changeChecked] = useState(
    day.startHour && day.endHour ? true : false
  );

  const [startHour, StartHourDropdown] = useDropdown(day.startHour || 9, hours);
  const [endHour, EndHourDropdown] = useDropdown(day.endHour || 18, hours);

  function useChecked() {
    changeChecked(!checked);
  }

  return (
    <HourPickerContainer checked={checked}>
          <p>
            De <StartHourDropdown name={`${label}-start`} /> à{" "}
            <EndHourDropdown name={`${label}-end`} />
          </p>
    </HourPickerContainer>
  );
};
```

when i use the component **Dropdown** returned by the hook i'm getting this error:

```
JSX element type 'StartHourDropdown' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

This component is working well but i can't compile without writing a ts ignore each time i call my component.

thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the confusion between constructors and instances.

Whenever we write a component in React:

```
class Greeter extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello, {this.props.hello}</div>;
    }
}
```

You use it this way:

```
return <Greeter hello='world' />;
```

and not this way:

```
let Greet = new Greeter();
return <Greet whoToGreet='world' />;
```

In the first example, we're passing around Greeter, the constructor function for our component. That's accurate usage. In the second example, we're passing around an instance of Greeter. That's incorrect, and will produce an error at runtime like "Object is not a function".

The problem with this code

```
function renderGreeting(Elem: React.Component<any, any>) {
    return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```

is that it's expecting an instance of React.Component. What we want is a function that takes a constructor for React.Component:

```
function renderGreeting(Elem: new() => React.Component<any, any>) {
    return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```

or similarly:

```
function renderGreeting(Elem: typeof React.Component) {
    return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```